# how to use own timestamp in mongodb index

Tags: php, mongodb, indexing

Now when insert data into Mongodb it will create unique value with current timestamp into _id field
,but I want to insert unique value with my own timestamp into the _id field.
can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

By default, MongoDB drivers (officially-supported ones, anyway) set the `_id` field to an `ObjectId`, a specialized data-type. If you'd like to override this, you can set the `_id` field to whatever data-type with whichever value you'd like.

[Reference](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs)